# USB Audio adapter not recognized after a power cycle without plug/unplug on Raspberry Pi 3/Ubuntu

Tags: raspberry-pi, ubuntu-16.04

I am using a Plugable USB Audio adapter to support voice input to my Raspberry Pi 3 running Ubuntu 16.04.  When I try to open the audio device using the ALSA driver in my code the first time after a power cycle it almost always fails, but if I unplug and replug it, it succeeds.  It does not fail after a reboot but does after another power cycle.  It appears that the OS does not recognize it without plugging it in after power is on.

Do others experience this?  Is there a way to make it available without physically plug/unplug?

Comment: I fails to open in the same way for writing to the driver as well, with my code or aplay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if I put the open in a while loop and repeated it, it eventually succeeded (without replugging the USB device).  It seems to require about 6 sec before succeeding after a reboot, after that it opens on first attempt.